# Cosmos DB TransactionalBatch error after update to dotnet 5

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, .net-5

I have some methods on my base repository to do some batch operations on Cosmos DB, they are like that:

```
public async Task AddRangeAsync(List<T> entities)
    {
        var container = _cosmosDbClientFactory.GetContainer(CollectionName);
        var entitiesList = entities.Split(_maxItemsPerBatch).ToList();

        foreach (var items in entitiesList)
        {
            var partitionKey = ResolvePartitionKey(items.FirstOrDefault());
            var transactionalBatch = container.CreateTransactionalBatch(partitionKey);

            items.ToList().ForEach(item => transactionalBatch.CreateItem(item));

            var result = await transactionalBatch.ExecuteAsync();

            if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new CosmosDbBatchOperationException(result.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Today I migrated the dotnet version of my project, from dotnet 3.1 to 5, after that I'm getting this error:

> System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serialization.HybridRow.Result> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serialization.HybridRow.RecordIO.RecordIOStream.ReadRecordIOAsync(System.IO.Stream, System.Func`2<System.ReadOnlyMemory`1<Byte>,Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serialization.HybridRow.Result>, System.Func`2<System.ReadOnlyMemory`1<Byte>,Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serialization.HybridRow.Result>, Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serialization.HybridRow.MemorySpanResizer`1)'.

This occurs in this line:

```
var result = await transactionalBatch.ExecuteAsync();
```

Version Info:

- Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos on v3.17.0
- Dotnet 5.0.201

Somebody knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked all my projects and they are referecing the same sdk version, so I cleaned my solution and deleted all obj and bin folders and tried again but it didn't work.
Then I tried this [solution](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/2292#issuecomment-804484606) because I was using **Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.17.0** with **AspNetCore.HealthChecks.CosmosDb 5.0.3**, so I downgraded **AspNetCore.HealthChecks.CosmosDb** to version **3.1.2** and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be hitting the same problem as discussed in this [SDK issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/2292).

A full binary clean and rebuild is worth trying to clear up dependency conflicts for `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serialization.HybridRow.dll`. If that doesn't work you could try adding your details to that issue thread.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that github discuss, I tried to delete **obj** and **bin** folders but It didn't fix it.

Comment: It may help to share your `csproj` file or other details about dependencies in use.